# How to change how data load is triggered by #each

Tags: ember.js

Using ember-data-latest.js, revision 4, RESTAdapter on top of Rails 3.2 + ActiveModel::Serializers.

Relevant Ember.js snippets:

```
App.List = DS.Model.extend({
    name:   DS.attr('string'),
    people: DS.hasMany('App.Person')
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    list: DS.belongsTo('App.List')
});

App.router = Ember.Router.create({
    enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            redirectsTo: 'lists'
        }),
        lists: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/lists',
            connectOutlets: function (router) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('lists', App.store.findAll(App.List));
            },
            showList: Ember.Route.transitionTo('list')
        }),
        list: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/lists/:id',
            serialize: function(router, context){
                return {id: context.get('id')};
            },
            deserialize: function(router, urlParams){
                return App.store.find(App.List, urlParams.id);
            },
            connectOutlets: function (router, context) {
                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('list', context);
            }
        }),
        showLists: Ember.Route.transitionTo('lists')
    })
});
```

When I load the app, it starts at the list index page, and it hits /lists on the backend to fetch the data (in which I include the child person ids for each list).  When I click on a list, it goes to the list show page.  In that template, I have the following:

```
{{#each person in people}}
  <li>{{person.name}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

At that time it makes a call like this to the backend to fetch the person data:

```
/people?ids[]=4&ids[]=5&ids[]=6
```

My question is: How can I alter the behavior so it uses a saner method that scales better, such as:

```
/people?list_id=1
```

or:

```
/list/1/people
```

Lists might have thousands of people, and generating a URL with a list of all ids seems like a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

Don't include the child person ids in your api response for the list. I believe this should result in the people API call working as you want.

Comment: Just tried that.  I commented out the "has_many :people" and "embed :ids" lines in ListSerializer.  Now when I go to the list show page, it doesn't invoke any requests against the backend at all, just shows and empty list with zero people records.

Comment: Bummer. It may be too challenging, but if you put together a JSFiddle with a self-contained example of the issue, I'd be happy to take a look and see what I can figure out. You might also check out the relationship-improvements branch and this PR: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/378

Comment: I don't think I can capture it in a fiddle because the behavior is related to hitting an external backend, and I don't have anything in production I can point to.  I'll just have to wait until I have time to read the Ember-Data source for the answer.